# ajax и window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Делаю сайт с новостями, при нажатии на кнопку <kbd>read more</kbd>(открытие полной новости), новость подгружается с *php* файла через *ajax* и меняет `window.location.hash` на `id` данной новости. Как сделать так чтобы при открытии ссылки с уже существующим `window.location.hash` открывалась эта новость?

Код, который подгружает новость и присваивает hash:

```
$('.contentshortnews').on('click', '.full-opener', function(){
    var newsid = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('http://jarwis-master.ru/php/newsget.php',
        {
            newsid: newsid
        },
        function(data){
            window.location.hash = 'news-'+newsid;
            $('.datanews').html(data);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Обработать событие загрузки сайта и в нем проверить существующий хеш. Для того, чтоб выполнить код после загрузки сайта, в jquery есть много способов. Один из них - такой:

```
$(function() {
    // this code will be executed on page load
});
```

Вопросы рефакторинга кода для устранения копипасты оставлю вам.

Также советую обработать событие hashchange, чтоб при ручном (и не только) изменении хеша тоже подгружалась нужная страница. Только осторожнее с этим - если лишнее навешаете, есть опасность ухода в бесконечную рекурсию, т.к. при изменении хеша при помощи javascript это событие тоже будет вызываться. Я рекомендую в обработчике нажатия на read more не выполнять загрузку страницы, а просто поменять хеш, а загрузку поручить уже обработчику hashchange. В прочем, я не знаю всех деталей вашей задачи - возможно, вам понадобится другая логика (например, если вы захотите сделать скроллинг к этой новости при открытии).

Answer (score 1):

Вынести подгрузку новости в отдельную функцию, и на старте проверять есть ли `window.location.hash`:

```
$(function() {

    $('.contentshortnews').on('click', '.full-opener', function(){
        readMore($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    function readMore(newsid) {
        $.post('http://jarwis-master.ru/php/newsget.php',
            {
                newsid: newsid
            },
            function(data){
                window.location.hash = 'news-'+newsid;
                $('.datanews').html(data);
            }
        );
    }

    if (window.location.hash) {
        readMore(window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
    }

});
```